# How to use NGINX now that HTACCESS is deprecated on elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS are now depreciating all their versions of Apache on Elastic Beanstalk, which means I can suddenly no longer use .htaccess files to rewrite urls.

No matter how much I read their ebextensions documentation, I can't seem to find out how to replace this functionality.

I've tried placing the following file in:

```
/.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf
```

With the following code:

```
location / {try_files $uri $uri/ /test.php?$args;}
```

It seems like Elastic Beanstalk doesn't even recognize the config file, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong here with my package?